# Querying Two Tables For Overlapping Ranges

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in Access 2007, each defines a ValueFrom and ValueTo column to express a range, such as from 1 to 10 or from 7 to 15.

I am trying to figure out how to issue a single query that would return the overlapping ranges in the two tables. I feel like I'm missing something...

Given these two tables:

```
Table01
ValueFrom   ValueTo
1           10
5           15
25          50
500         600

Table02
ValueFrom   ValueTo
1           12
16          24
30          40
45          100
500         600
```

I would want this as output

```
RESULTS FROM QUERY
Table01_ValueFrom   Table01_ValueTo   Table02_ValueFrom   Table02_ValueTo
1                   10                1                   12
5                   15                <emptystring>       <emptystring>
25                  50                30                  40
25                  50                45                  100
500                 600               500                 600
```

The above results indicate range 1-10 in Table01 overlaps range 1-12 in Table 02; that range 5-15 in Table01 doesn't overlap any Table02 ranges a range in Table 02; that range 25-50 overlaps two rows in Table02, 30-40 and 45-100.

Notice that this query must detect partial and full range overlaps.

Any ideas on this one? It's okay to use psuedocode or even make a suggestion on how to approach this problem. While I can write a program to do the above, I am trying to solve with a single Access query.

Thank you!

Comment: Uh, the range 5-15 does overlap with 1-12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal SQL, you could do this as a `JOIN`:

```
select t1.ValueFrom, t1.ValueTo, t2.ValueFrom, t2.ValueTo
from table01 as t1 left join
     table02 as t2
     on t1.ValueFrom <= t2.ValueTo and t1.ValueTo >= t2.ValueFrom;
```

Unfortunately, MS Access does not permit inequalities in the `JOIN` conditions.  So, here is another way:

```
select t1.ValueFrom, t1.ValueTo, t2.ValueFrom, t2.ValueTo
from table01 as t1,
     table02 as t2
where t1.ValueFrom <= t2.ValueTo and t1.ValueTo >= t2.ValueFrom
union all
select t1.ValueFrom, t1.ValueTo, NULL, NULL
from table01 as t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table02 as t2
                  where t1.ValueFrom <= t2.ValueTo and t1.ValueTo >= t2.ValueFrom
                 );
```

Comment: That is unfortunate about MS Access' limitation on standard JOIN conditions. Thanks for the exceptional answer and explanation.

Comment: Just realized that `cross join` is giving syntax error in Access 2007. Is Access 2010 required for that? Any substitute for Access 2007 (upgrading is not an option for me, unfortunately, due to client constraints)...

Comment: I am not sure, but it might just be that I can issue a select from `table01, table 02` and get the same cross-join effect...

Comment: Gordon's answer didn't exactly work in Access 2007 as written, but I was able to query the two tables with `select t1.ValueFrom, t1.ValueTo, t2.ValueFrom, t2.ValueTo from table01 as t1, table02 as t2` and that got me the rest of the way. Marking as answer because it's close enough and Gordon's answer really helped pull me out of a bind.